# Java API HBase Regions Metrics and state

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to find the way to get the following information using HBase(1.2.0-cdh5.8.0) Java API for each table:

- Online Regions
- Offline Regions
- Failed Regions
- Split Regions
- Other Regions

So basically a set of information visible from HBase UI.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. The two easiest and most standard ways are:

1. **HBase Admin API**: You can extract a lot of information about different components in an HBase cluster and perform almost all cluster management tasks using the HBase Admin API. If you are writing code in Java, you'll need to have hbase client jar in your classpath. Have a look at the admin api javadoc [here](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html).
   For your specific purpose in this question; the part you are interested in is the *ClusterStatus* that can be retrieved using the admin api.
2. **Metrics collection through HBase Master's JMX port**:
   This has no dependencies on any HBase libraries. You just need to enable the JMX support in HBase (See [HBase metrics](https://hbase.apache.org/metrics.html)). Then you can just curl on the JMX port of any HBase master and extract the metrics you want (and many more).